# question was wrongly closed as opinated

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

the question [What location in Europe is known for its pipe organs?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/161861/what-location-in-europe-is-known-for-its-pipe-organs) was closed incorrectly as opinion based.

I edited (peer review applies) the title to "**Which are the locations of Europe's largest pipe organs**?", to run away from the "opinion-based" close reason

As by FAQ https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask it doesn't qualify and it doesn't match the *and it's not about …* section of this FAQ https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic neither.

I think the question doesn't fall in any of the close worthy categories and should be reopened.

What's your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the header of that question needs more editting still.
When I answered it I took the question to ask for 'how to find those organs'.

If the question is edited that way but so that the current answers still fit to the new version the question will meet the rules.

PS, I edited and voted to re-open.

Answer (score 8):

You've changed the question in the way that made the answers useless, because they point to the organs that are 'quite big', but without claims they are the biggest.

Edits to the question shouldn't IMHO punish the answerers, because now it looks like they posted answers that don't answer the question.

Sometimes it's better to close the question and make the OP to rethink it, instead of spoonfeeding that creates chaos.

Comment: The original question didn't even ask about size;  it just asked for "a very good organ".  Bigger is not necessarily the same thing as better.